# What is the difference between org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect vs. org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE, Hibernate, PostgreSQL 9.6.0.x . I see IntelliJ IDEA suggest 2 dialects:

```
# Hibernate config
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres Plus extend PostgreSQL dialect with added compatibility for Oracle functions